# Display form input data from one fieldset to another fieldset using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to display all the form input values from a fieldset to next fieldset for reviewing and then submit using submit button.

I have searched for solution on Google and found that it can be achieved using jquery serialize. But I want it to display as a form but with disabled fields.

Please guide me to the right direction.

This is my code.

```js
//jQuery time
var current_fs, newdc, adc, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches



//Review New Domain Controller
$(".review").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $('.newdcreview');
    
    //show the next fieldset
    $('.newdcreview').show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    $('.newdc').animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
            $('.newdcreview').css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});




$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

```css
/*custom font*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
    height: 100%;
    
    
}

body {
    font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 20px 30px;
    
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10% 50px;
    
    /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
    position: absolute;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
    width: 100px;
    background: #27AE60;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}

.main {
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#msform .main .action-button {
    width: 250px;
    background: #27AE60;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #2C3E50;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<form id="msform">
    
    
    <fieldset class="newdc">
        <h2 class="fs-title">New Domain Controller</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Fill all the fields below</h3>
        <input type="text" name="ip" id="ip" placeholder="IP" />
        <input type="text" name="subnet" id="subnet" placeholder="Subnet Mask" />
        <input type="text" name="gateway" id="gateway" placeholder="Gateway" />
        <input type="text" name="hostname" id="hostname" placeholder="Hostname" />
        <input type="text" name="domain" id="domain" placeholder="Domain Admin Name" />
        <input type="text" name="netbios" id="netbios" placeholder="NetBios Name" />
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="text" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Re-enter Password" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="review action-button" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="newdcreview">
        <h2 class="fs-title">New Domain Controller</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Fill all the fields below</h3>
        <input type="text" class="show_ip" readonly="readonly" />
        <input type="text" class="show_subnet" readonly="readonly" />
        <input type="text" class="show_gateway" readonly="readonly" />
        <input type="text" class="show_hostname" readonly="readonly" />
        <input type="text" class="show_domain" readonly="readonly" />
        <input type="text" class="show_netbios" readonly="readonly" />
        <input type="text" class="show_password" readonly="readonly" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Confirm" />
    </fieldset>
    
</form>
```